# Synchronized annotation doens't working in Kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, mobile, synchronization

I've a foreground service and i'm executing this method:

```
Controller().threadTest()
Controller().threadTest()
```

And my Controller class is:

```
class Controller{
    
        fun threadTest(){
            Thread(Runnable{
                threadOperation()
            }).start()
    
        }
    
        @Synchronized
        private fun threadOperation(){
            println("Thread start")
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            println("Thread finish")
        }
}
```

But the @Synchronized isn't working, because my log is:

```
Thread start
Thread start
Thread finish
Thread finish
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Synchronized` annotation only prevents concurrent execution of a function in calls on the same instance. In your case, you are creating two instances of `Controller()`.

You will get the expected behavior (calls execution one-by-one) if you modify the calling code so that it creates only one instance of your class, for example:

```
val controller = Controller()
controller.threadTest()
controller.threadTest()
```

Or, if you need mutual exclusion of concurrent calls on multiple `Controller` instances, you have to either move `@Synchronized` to another class whose instance both `Controller`s will reference or use other concurrency utilities, such as [`withLock`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.concurrent.locks.-lock/with-lock.html) calls on a shared lock.